# Oracle Sql trigger not working

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a very simple trigger, that prints out the username and date when a new row is inserted into the users table. But after it successfully compiled, the trigger didn't get triggered (there was no output in the dbms window). So, I simplified my code until I got this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logger
AFTER INSERT ON USERS
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('User added with name:');
END;
```

If I run the code in the SQL worksheet (from BEGIN to END), I can see the output, but not when I try to use the trigger. Where is the problem?

Comment: From my point of view there is no point to use a trigger to print something when it’s triggered. To do something more feasible, why dont you try to insert something in some table and you see if it works?

Comment: Your problem is that `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` is aimed to write to console. So, you need to have the trigger making some change that could be checked without using the console. You can, for instance, send an e-mail to yourself (just to test that the trigger is fired, not as the normal functionality of the trigger).

Comment: I completely agree with @Jaime Drq and @FDavidov. Besides, if you really want to see on the console, then you need to issue `set serveroutput on` command without need of `begin .. end` unless you call from an external application.

Comment: I know, that there is no point of the code, this is an assignment for my class. The task is to create any trigger, and I choose to print the name and date of the registration.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options, one is that the trigger is not firing, the other is that it is, but you're not seeing the output.

1. Assuming you're working in a console program like sqlplus, make sure to do `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` before inserting your row.
2. If that doesn't fix it, then make sure the trigger is firing. Try creating a simple table:

   CREATE TABLE logtable ( msg VARCHAR2(30 CHAR));

Next, add this to your trigger,

```
INSERT INTO logtable( msg ) VALUES ( 'trigger fired' );
```

Then, try your insert again.